# how to solve the warning "syscall not implemented"

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

When I do make modules it will give this warning and later modules are build. But without implement myown system call "mycall" whats the use of build modules

```
root@akshit-Vostro-1550:~/Desktop/Device_Drivers/newsource/linux-2.6.32# make modules
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/linux/utsrelease.h
  SYMLINK include/asm -> include/asm-x86
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
<stdin>:1523:2: warning: #warning syscall mycall not implemented [-Wcpp]
```

Comment: Please someone help me to get out this problem

Comment: Can we see your code ? And a uname -a ? kernel 2.6, i see

Comment: Thats not a code i am compiling a kernel linux 2.6.32 at that time i get that type of warning                          uname -a :-                                                                                           Linux akshit-Vostro-1550 3.19.0-41-generic #46~14.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 8 17:46:10 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Ok apparently you found your missing syscall

Answer (score 1):

I solved by adding this line

## define __NR_mycall 298

__SYSCALL(__NR_mycall, sys_mycall)

to arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_64.h